# Fetch streams from UDP multicast address

Tags: c, networking, udp, multicast

I'm writing a program that receives the UDP streams that are sent to a multicast group address. Assume that I have an address like `udp://249.0.0.1`. To this address, I receive two streams to two different ports, say 2500 and 2600. I need to write a C program that fetches both streams from the different port within a single program. Can you suggest a starting point (tutorials, useful APIs, …)?

Comment: Essentially, you want some one to write the basics of a multicast client for you for free?  There's tons of example code and tutorials on the web describing exactly how to do this.

Comment: @Mark Mann: I am sorry, but i could'nt find any help on the net

Comment: Here's a couple that look decent: http://www.tenouk.com/Module41c.html http://www.tack.ch/multicast/ and here's a couple of books http://www.nmsl.cs.ucsb.edu/MulticastSocketsBook/ and http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Sockets-Networking/dp/0131411551 (the bible).  If you haven't read Stevens, I highly recommend it.  It will explain multiplexing several connections as well as multicast socket programming.

Comment: @Mark Mann: Thanks a lot. It will be a great help.. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Richard Stevens' bible is excellent. If you start with his TCP Illustrated book http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Vol-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469/ you will get a complete understanding of the whole topic from theoretical to practical level.

Comment: FYI: `249.0.0.1` is not a multicast address.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 UDP sockets, register both for multicast address.

You can fetch data either with:

- 2 processes (fork), blocking sockets.
- 2 threads (pthread), blocking sockets.
- 1 thread, non-blocking sockets. For the demultiplexing you need select, poll or epoll.

Comment: thanks once again yi_H... 
when i use select, poll or epoll i will be able to listen to only one port at a time. but need to continuously listen to both the ports. :(

Comment: all of them were especially designed to listen to mulitple file descriptors simultaneously (you can even mix sockets, pipes, standard io). code examples of stevens' book are available online, check them.